# Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have Python Falcon app running in a docker.I am trying to work local before deploying it on elastic beanstalk. When i am trying to connect local DynamoDB which is running in an another Docker, i get the following error.

```
hayirlisi_test | Traceback (most recent call last):
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
hayirlisi_test |     (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
hayirlisi_test |     raise err
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
hayirlisi_test |     sock.connect(sa)
hayirlisi_test | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
hayirlisi_test |
hayirlisi_test | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
hayirlisi_test |
hayirlisi_test | Traceback (most recent call last):
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 258, in send
hayirlisi_test |     decode_content=False,
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
hayirlisi_test |     _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 343, in increment
hayirlisi_test |     raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
hayirlisi_test |     raise value
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
hayirlisi_test |     chunked=chunked)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
hayirlisi_test |     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
hayirlisi_test |     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 125, in _send_request
hayirlisi_test |     method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
hayirlisi_test |     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
hayirlisi_test |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 152, in _send_output
hayirlisi_test |     self.send(msg)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 236, in send
hayirlisi_test |     return super(AWSConnection, self).send(str)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
hayirlisi_test |     self.connect()
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
hayirlisi_test |     conn = self._new_conn()
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
hayirlisi_test |     self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
hayirlisi_test | urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPConnection object at 0x7fb2fd187128>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection r
efused
hayirlisi_test |
hayirlisi_test | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
hayirlisi_test |
hayirlisi_test | Traceback (most recent call last):
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
hayirlisi_test |     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
hayirlisi_test |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/falcon/api.py", line 244, in __call__
hayirlisi_test |     responder(req, resp, **params)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/code/app.py", line 54, in on_get
hayirlisi_test |     'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
hayirlisi_test |     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
hayirlisi_test |     operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
hayirlisi_test |     return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
hayirlisi_test |     return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
hayirlisi_test |     success_response, exception):
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 231, in _needs_retry
hayirlisi_test |     caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
hayirlisi_test |     return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
hayirlisi_test |     return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
hayirlisi_test |     response = handler(**kwargs)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
hayirlisi_test |     if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
hayirlisi_test |     caught_exception)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
hayirlisi_test |     return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
hayirlisi_test |     caught_exception)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
hayirlisi_test |     attempt_number, caught_exception)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
hayirlisi_test |     raise caught_exception
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
hayirlisi_test |     http_response = self._send(request)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 244, in _send
hayirlisi_test |     return self.http_session.send(request)
hayirlisi_test |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 278, in send
hayirlisi_test |     raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
hayirlisi_test | botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```

My DynamoDB variable declaration looks like this

```
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', aws_access_key_id="anything",aws_secret_access_key="anything",region_name="local",endpoint_url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/%22)
```

I tried running DynamoDB docker with "-sharedDB" parameter also. However, i cant figure out what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running this in two docker containers there are a few things that need to happen. First, `localhost` is local *to the container*. That is, you are calling the container's localhost, not your machine's localhost.

You will need to make the other containers viewable to each other. This can be accomplished through [`networks`](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/). So, you'll need to set this up like so:

```
docker network create test_network
```

Then you can run your containers on that network like so:

```
docker run -p <host>:<container> --network=test_network -n <container_name> <image>
```

Now the url in your container will be the `name` of the container that you set up:

```
myendpoint = 'http://<container_name>:<container_port>'
```

To see the containers on that network, you can run

```
docker network inspect test_network
```

And look at the `containers` section. You will see the name, ip address, etc. The reason you want to name your container is because the names are random unless you specify it, and that doesn't do you much better over trying to find a container by it's ip address

Comment: That was the error. I runned my falcon app using "docker-compose up" and after that i get the network name of my app using "docker network ls". I have runned dynamodb image as you said but with my app network. Problem solved.